# What is the fastest way to destroy Junkrat's tire?

Tags: overwatch

As the title states, what is the quickest method for taking out the 100 Health on Junkrat's Rip Tire? I would like to know in terms of damage and accuracy, as pure damage can't always guarantee an easy hit on the tire. Damage dealing ultimates can be included as well.

I play primarily on PS4, so being snap-accurate is difficult, but answers tailored to both console and PC are acceptable.

Comment: You basically want something that can deal 100 health of damage in one go. Reinhardt's Flame Strike, 76's Helix Rocket, and others are all good candidates for this

Comment: @Unionhawk I usually have good luck with Roadhog's Alt. Fire, but hitting that small sphere of pain is pretty difficult, especially on console. I should specify that...

Comment: i can't say I understand the downvotes. Anyone care to explain?

Comment: Some may think this is "too broad"? I dont know, I think it was a well worded question so I voted it up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the tire moves quickly, accuracy is often much more useful than raw damage when dealing with the rip tire. To that end, Soldier 76 is very effective at killing it quickly, assuming that he hears it coming and has time to prepare. His regular fire does decent damage with good accuracy from very far away. His Helix Rockets also one-shot the tire. Widowmaker (or even Hanzo) of course are also very accurate and do a lot of damage, so they can also clear the tire.

A second option is another Junkrat. Junkrat's concussion mine does 120 damage, so placing it where you think the tire will travel is a good way to blow it up. Pharah rockets are similar thanks to the long range and splash damage.

Roadhog's alt fire is an okay tactic, though it can be hard to hit. You have to be at just the right distance, otherwise it will either miss most of it's damage or it won't scatter at all.

If you can't kill the tire fast enough, another option is to dodge it entirely. Wait for it to come close, then use an ability to become invulnerable and trick the enemy Junkrat into detonating early. Reaper, Mei, and Tracer all have abilities that allow them to do that.

The best way to counter Junkrat's rip tire is to be aware of your surroundings.

Comment: And Bastion can destroy it in about .2 seconds. Call it half a second if about half his shots miss.

Comment: I guess a sniper might work if it was coming directly at you. Most people are going to have trouble hitting one moving at an angle. I end up destroying a lot of tires with Torbjorn's turret, but I also have a lot of turrets destroyed by the tire.

Comment: Symmetra's turrets can also be quite effective if placed on the path of the tire. They don't have the range of tobjorn's one though.

Comment: MCree's right click will do the trick if you are close enough, which entails its own risks. Depending on the skill of the Junkrat, you can often kill it before they get a chance to react and detonate. This is highly dependent on their reaction time, however, so YMMV.

Comment: @JamesCW That seems too risky to me. If you're close enough for your right click to be accurate enough to destroy the tire, the tire is also close enough to you to blow you up. I think McCree's primary fire is much more effective - it's accurate and only takes about 2 shots to destroy the tire.

Comment: This has mostly worked for me when I was already too close to successfully run away, so I didn't have much to lose. : )